# Java peer 2 peer - JXTA uses deprecated API

Tags: java, p2p, deprecated, jxta

I want to use peer 2 peer in Java, and I came across this question: [Developing Peer to Peer application in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920527/developing-peer-to-peer-application-in-java)

They advised to use JXSE/JXTA. It was pretty hard just to download the things I needed because the links are dead. I eventually managed to downloaded JXTA and tried to do the tutorial they provide, however, I get the following error message:

```
jxta-jxse-2.5-sources.jar(net/jxta/id/jxta/IDFormat.java):101: warning: [deprecation] URIInstantiator in IDFactory has been deprecated
public static final IDFactory.URIInstantiator INSTANTIATOR = new Instantiator();
                             ^
jxta-jxse-2.5-sources.jar(net/jxta/id/jxta/Instantiator.java):85: warning: [deprecation] URIInstantiator in IDFactory has been deprecated
final class Instantiator implements net.jxta.id.IDFactory.URIInstantiator {
```

So basically, a deprecated API. However, the website of JXTA says to use java version +1.4. I have already tried with the java 8,7,6, 1.4 and every single time I get the problem

Is JXTA completely outdated or how can I solve this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333072/why-has-jxta-been-abandoned-any-alternatives-out-there are you using 2.7?

Comment: Switch to maven (for its version dependency management in this case).

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jxta.platform/jxta

Comment: @JoopEggen I think the latest version is this one: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.kenai.jxse|jxse|2.7|bundle